# Remove aceton from denatured alcohol

Tags: solvents, extraction

I have bought a bottle of denatured alcohol. On the web I've found these solutions typically contain the following:

- $85\%$ ethanol
- $10\%$ water
- $3\%$ methanol
- $1\%$ aceton
- $1\%$ pyridine

I would like to get rid of the acetone. How can I remove it? (and how do I know if it is in my solution?)

Comment: Without any hplc or other high end equipment (just in the kitchen)

Comment: You should be able to distill the acetone and methanol off.

Comment: @A.K. What height would you suggest for the column?

Comment: Depending which country you're in, this could be illegal

Comment: @Beerhunter I live in the Netherlands, 1 liter distillation devices are legal. I'm not concerned about the methanol, just the aceton since it's not good for my printed circuitboards.

Comment: @MehdiNellen Just distill until the vapors reach the boiling point of ethanol or rather a few degrees shy.

Comment: Ethanol and water are going to azeotrope.  Also word of caution, just in case anyone might decide to take a swig, pyridine is fairly toxic even at low doses particularly for males and their reproductive systems.

Comment: If you have access you can stir then distill from CaH2 and get as much water out. Then stir over clean Mg turnings, either under nitrogen or otherwise protected from the air. Add a crystal or two of iodine to activate, and reflux it for some time. Then distill off the ethanol and residual water. Distillation from Raney nickel might do it, as would shaking it with 4 angstom molecular sieves. Point is its going to be tough.  Not sure its worth it for 1%.